# What material is an Inkjet transparent printing film (slide) made of?

Tags: materials

I don't mean [photographic film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_film)/[film base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_base) but rather the A4/Letter sheets of transparent film that were used in slide projectors during lectures. For example see [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Inkjet-Laser-Printing-A4-Transparency-Film-20-Sheets-for-Screen-Plate-Making-/181396274376).

Comment: It depends. There are several variants, depending on printer and cleaning solvent to use. However, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_(projection) states, A transparency, also known in industrial settings as a "viewfoil" or "foil", is a thin sheet of transparent flexible material, typically **cellulose acetate**, onto which figures can be drawn.

Comment: I would have thought polyester was more common as it is for laserjets.